# Cannot find header files after installing QGIS with apt on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis

I followed the [Official Install Tutorial](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) and installed QGIS2.8 or 3.0 using `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis`. I did not install `python-plugin-grass` because of dependency problem. The QGIS client 2.8 or 3.0 was running well. However, I cannot find header files of QGIS in directory `/usr` on Ubuntu. There were only shared libraries(.so) in `/usr/lib/qgis`.
How to install QGIS-api on Ubuntu? I want to write some code with the QGIS C++ API.

Comment: That makes sense! I installed dev package and find the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the binaries, not the headers.

You need to install `libqgis-dev` which apt tells me:

> This package contains the headers and libraries needed to develop plugins for QGIS.